# Get post data, in Checkout success observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I have added custom field on checkout page.

I want to get all the post data, in Checkout success observer,

Here is my observer code

```
<?php
/** 
 Author : Disha
 **/
 namespace Neo\OrderComment\Observer;

 use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

 class Orderneo implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
 {
    /** @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface **/
    protected $_logger;
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\HistoryFactory **/
    protected $_historyFactory;
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory **/
    protected $_orderFactory;
    /**
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\HistoryFactory
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory
     **/
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\HistoryFactory $historyFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory){
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_historyFactory = $historyFactory;
        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }
    /**
     * Add order comment, to the last placed order
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer
     **/
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {   
        // Get order id, of last placed order
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        foreach($orderIds as $orderId){
            $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);
        }
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->getRequest()->getPost());
        exit;
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error, as unknown method `getRequest()`,

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Neo\OrderComment\Observer\Orderneo::getRequest() in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Neo/OrderComment/Observer/Orderneo.php:42
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(73): Neo\OrderComment\Observer\Orderneo->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(61): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Neo\OrderComment\Observer\Orderneo), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('checkout_onepag...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success.php in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Neo/OrderComment/Observer/Orderneo.php on line 42
```

Comment: As an additional solution you can add the request to your class through dependency injection and access it via singleton

Comment: `Checkout success observer,` are u taking for which event?From where you have posted the data?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya already added this as an answer

Comment: @AmitBera I am using checkout_onepage_controller_success_action this event

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
protected $_request;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\HistoryFactory $historyFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
) { 
    $this->_request = $request;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    $this->_historyFactory = $historyFactory;
    $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
}
```

Inside function get post data as below way:

```
$this->_request->getPost();
```

Don't forget to clear **var/generation** folder.

Comment: I am getting this error, after implementing yours

Comment: Argument 4 passed to Neo\OrderComment\Observer\Orderneo::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context, none given

Comment: I have updated my answer and remove var/generation folder before check.

Comment: okay thnks @Rakesh, I will check.

Comment: let me know if you have issue after updated answer.

Comment: yes I am checking @Rakesh

Comment: @MrunmayDeswandikar run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure you need to replace:

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost()
```

With:

```
$observer->getRequest()->getPost()
```

But it may depend on the event you're observing IIRC.

Comment: Okay let me check @Raphel